# Why Swift 5 read local json always nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I've read lots of SO question on it, but they are not applying in my case.

I follow the steps mentioned in [Parse JSON from file and URL with Swift](https://programmingwithswift.com/parse-json-from-file-and-url-with-swift/), project structure is:

[image]

The code:

```swift
import Foundation

struct DemoData: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
}

func readLocalFile(forName name: String) -> Data? {
    do {
        if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name,
                                             ofType: "json"),
            let jsonData = try String(contentsOfFile: bundlePath).data(using: .utf8) {
            return jsonData
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    return nil
}

func parse(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DemoData.self,
                                                   from: jsonData)
        
        print("Title: ", decodedData.title)
        print("Description: ", decodedData.description)
        print("===================================")
    } catch {
        print("decode error")
    }
}

if let localData = readLocalFile(forName: "data") {
    print("running")
    parse(jsonData: localData)
} else {
    print("final nil")
}
```

And it turn out to be:

```sh
final nil
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

PS: Config of the json data
[image]

Comment: Is `bundlePath` nil? Also, `readLocalFile` is supposed to return `Data?`, but in fact `jsonData` is a `String`, don't you have a warning/error?

Comment: Make sure the json file is added to the app target (open inspector view, click checkbox to add to your app target).

Comment: @BradleyMackey Thanks for your remind, I just added the json file to target app, but still got `nil`

Comment: @Larme `jsonData` is `Data` acutally :) Xcode didn't show any warning/error

Comment: Oh, I focused on `String(contentsOfFile:)`, but didn't see `.data(using:)` since that's doing 2 conversions while you could init it directly with `Data(contentsOfFile:)`... So, which value is failing in your `if let`?

Comment: @Larme Throw Error in `let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json")` , I believe that the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You are suppressing some potential errors, I recommend this (generic) version, it `throws` all possible errors</strike>

```
enum ReadError : Error { case fileIsMissing }

func readLocalFile<T : Decodable>(forName name: String) throws -> T {
    
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name,
                            withExtension: "json") else {
                               throw ReadError.fileIsMissing
                            }
       
    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
}
```

---

```
do {
    let localData : DemoData = try readLocalFile(forName: "data")
    print("===================================")
    print("running")
    print("Title: ", localData.title)
    print("Description: ", localData.description)
    print("===================================")
} catch {
    print("An error occured", error)
}
```

---

**Edit:**

**Your code doesn't work because your target is a command line tool.** [image]

**CLIs don't have a bundle therefore there is no Resources folder either.**

Comment: Got error `Instance method 'decode(_:from:)' requires that 'T' conform to 'Decodable'` in line `return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: jsonData)`

Comment: Yup, not  I got `An error occured fileIsMissing` right now, not sure why this error happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the text encoding format of the json file. Please check and it should be `Unicode (UTF-8)` since you're using text encoding format as `.utf8` in `readLocalFile` file method.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've update the Text Encoding to `Unicode (UTF-8)`, but still got nil :(

Comment: I've tried the same code in my system and it worked. I'm sure there is something problem with the text encoding. Kindly have a relook at it.